# OutputCache for partialView not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, outputcache

**Hi,**

I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 website where I have created a action that returns a partial view. This view have the following :

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10000" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

And to render this from my main view I use this :

```
<% Html.RenderAction("ImageWall", "Image"); %>
```

The problem is that it is not caching at all? When setting a breakpoint I can see that the expensive drawing is running everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, Use Action Attribute

```
<OutputCache(Duration:=10000, VaryByParam:="any")> 
Function ImageWall() As PartialViewResult
   Return PartialView()
End Function
```

For Vb.Net sample, sorry